# The path is not valid. Check the directory for the database. [Path = (Localdb)\v11.0]

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on an MVC web application using SQL Server and Entity Framework (first timer).  I've got a lot of forms that add stuff into the data tables and such using (Localdb)\v11.0 and I know there is data there.

My next step that I'm currently working on is adding a login/register function.  So I've added

```
try
{
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.Write(e);
}
```

into my Global.asax.cs file in the Application_Start method.

My Default Connection is

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(Localdb)\v11.0;Encrypt=False" />
```

And that, of course, is set in my web.config.

Now when I step through the code, it throws an exception saying that there is no database located at (Localdb)\v11.0

There's probably something simply I'm overlooking as I couldn't find anything useful through my good friend google.

Comment: look at this site it's very useful and will definitely come in hand in your future [ConnectionString.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string for LocalDb should look something like this (assuming the mdf file is in the app_data folder inside your solution:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\filename.mdf"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: I saw this solution in my research, but it seems that every time I try to implement this solution, I get an error saying that "AttachDBFilename" is not a valid attribute.